# F10 isn't working properly in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, debugging

When project is stopped (not in the debugging state) and you press F10, normally the debugging session starts and VS stops at the entry point (e.g. Program.Main). That always worked for me in VS2005 and works OK in VS2008. But recently that stopped working in my VS2005 - the project just runs as if I pressed F5, so I have to place a breakpoint at Program.Main when I need to stop at the entry point. Though it continues to work as it should in my VS2008.
I suspect, that's because I installed Reflector add-in and it changed some settings in VS2005, but I just can't find out which settings. Also, disabling that add-in has no effect on my issue :-(

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a question? It's not apparent.

Comment: The question is how to make F10 work like it should. Please sorry, I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution

1) switch on the 'Just My Code' option

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code

2) restart VS

voila